# Python BallSwitchBall problem. Issue with time performance

Tags: python, matrix, performance-testing

I have issues with the time performance when I am doing performance tests on my code.

So, I designed this algorithm and the results, with the values given by my professor at college which were correct. The problem is, the time performance is off. I suppose this is because I have many nested if's and for loops. Is there a more optimal way of doing this?

def solution(A, K):

```
mov = -1
pmov = -1
ball_out = False
right_mov = False
down_mov = False
n = 0
count = 0
if (K == 0):
    return 0
while (n < K):
    for i in range(0,(len(A[0])-1)):
        for j in range(0,(len(A))-1):
            if (A[i][j] == -1):
                mov = -1
                if(A[i][j-1] == -1):
                    pmov = -1
                    down_mov = True
                    right_mov = False
                elif(A[i][j-1] == 1):
                    pmov = 1
                    down_mov = False
                    right_mov = True
                elif(A[i][j-1] == 0):
                    pmov = 0
            elif (A[i][j] == 1):
                mov = 1
                if(A[i][j-1] == -1):
                    pmov = -1
                    down_mov = True
                    right_mov = False
                elif(A[i][j-1] == 1):
                    pmov = 1
                    down_mov = False
                    right_mov = True
                elif(A[i][j-1] == 0):
                    pmov = 0
            elif (A[i][j] == 0):
                mov = 0
                if(A[i][j-1] == -1):
                    pmov = -1
                    down_mov = True
                    right_mov = False
                elif(A[i][j-1] == 1):
                    pmov = 1
                    down_mov = False
                    right_mov = True
                elif(A[i][j-1] == 0):
                    pmov = 0

    if (A[i-1][j-1] == -1 and down_mov == True):
        count += 1
    elif (A[i-1][j-1] == 0 and down_mov == True):
        count += 1
    elif (A[i-1][j-1] == 1):
        pass

    return count



    A = [[-ele for ele in item] for item in A]
    #negamos la matriz


    n += 1







pass
```